# How to inspect element in Android Phone using UC Browser?

Tags: android, html, cross-browser, web-inspector, uc-browser

I need to inspect DOM in Mobile UC Browser. I also tried Desktop UC Browser like chrome inspector with this link `ucbrowser://inspect/#devices`, but it is not working.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html Try this